# Ubuntu Software: Unable to install app

Tags: software-installation

When I tried to install Visual Studio Code or any other software in Ubuntu Software Application, I get this notification:

```
Unable to install "Visual Studio Code":
status-code=409 kind=snap-change-conflict message=snap
"code" has "install-snap" change in progress
```

But VS Code is installed a few seconds later. What is the problem here?

This was the case when I installed another application, too. It gave me this notification but installed the application a few seconds later.

I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of issue can happen when one of two situations happen:

1. Snap is doing something in the background
2. The Internet connection is inconsistent

You can check the first item by opening a terminal and running `snap changes`, which may give you a list that looks like this:

```
555  Doing   2021-06-19T09:12:11Z  -  Install "cookies" snap
556  Doing   2021-06-19T09:12:12Z  -  Update "milk" snap
```

If you think something is taking too long or blocking other processes, you can end a snap process like this:

```
sudo snap abort 555
```

After this you may find snaps install without first complaining. However, if the network connection is unstable, a `snap install` may fail to connect to the snap store to download the application. This will result in an error, but the install request is now queued and may successfully connect and download a few seconds later.

If the issue is intermittent, it could be either possible situations. If the issue is consistent, it’s probably the second item.

Comment: Is it okay to end snap process? I checked snap processes with`snap changes` there was no ongoing processes. So I think it is probably Internet connection because I use wifi. But I used this wifi before and there was no problem with installing apps